# status "Preparing" for more than 2 hours for 350MB file

Tags: automl, azure-machine-learning-service

I have submitted autoML run on remote compute (Standard_D12_v2 - 4 node cluster 28GB, 4 cores each)

My input file is roughly 350 MB.

the status is "Preparing" for more than 2 hours. And then it fails.

```
User error: Run timed out. No model completed training in the specified time. Possible solutions: 
1) Please check if there are enough compute resources to run the experiment. 
2) Increase experiment timeout when creating a run. 
3) Subsample your dataset to decrease featurization/training time.
```

below is my python-Notebook code, please help.

```
import azureml.core
from azureml.core.experiment import Experiment
from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
from azureml.core.dataset import Dataset
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget
from azureml.train.automl import AutoMLConfig



ws = Workspace.from_config()
experiment=Experiment(ws, 'nyc-taxi')




cpu_cluster_name = "low-cluster"
compute_target = ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name=cpu_cluster_name)


data = "https://betaml4543906917.blob.core.windows.net/betadata/2015_08.csv"
dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(data)
training_data, validation_data = dataset.random_split(percentage=0.8, seed=223)
label_column_name = 'totalAmount'



automl_settings = {
    "n_cross_validations": 3,
    "primary_metric": 'normalized_root_mean_squared_error',
    "enable_early_stopping": True,
    "max_concurrent_iterations": 2, # This is a limit for testing purpose, please increase it as per cluster size
    "experiment_timeout_hours": 2, # This is a time limit for testing purposes, remove it for real use cases, this will drastically limit ablity to find the best model possible
    "verbosity": logging.INFO,
}

automl_config = AutoMLConfig(task = 'regression',
                             debug_log = 'automl_errors.log',
                             compute_target = compute_target,
                             training_data = training_data,
                             label_column_name = label_column_name,
                             **automl_settings
                            )




remote_run = experiment.submit(automl_config, show_output = False)
```

Comment: I've definitely seen that before. I believe that this is a control between the iteration time out time and the total experiment timeout. Keep in mind that featurization must complete before AutoML can run. What version of the SDK are you running?

Comment: I am using  version 
1.11.0

Comment: Based on my understanding, featurization must complete before any models are run. Featurization is a sequential process that featurizes one column at a time, so depending on the data types in each column (categoricals, text, etc.), this process varies in time. Control for iteration_timeout and experiment_timeout. Last time I used this (which there's a good chance they solved this problem), I used to put iteration_timeout + 2 hours as my experiment_timeout. So definitely increase your experiment_timeout and start controlling your iteration_timeout till it runs through

Comment: thank you so much for your input. I will make the changes accordingly for experiment run and let you know